# Not able to call Multiple API Parallely using Retrofit kotlin rxjava and how to call flatMap and zip together with Common Place error handling

Tags: kotlin, zip, retrofit, rx-java, flatmap

What i want to achive is

Call IndexList API and display the responded list in a spinner -> Click on Spinner item i want to call 3 api in parallel using .zip operator and display in DetailViewModel

I am using flatmap for calling api in sequence
In first flatmap i am calling IndexList api and i am passing IndexList response to call 3 multiple api in parallel using Observable.zip operator but i am not able
to achive the second part of calling 3 API in parallel and display in view model

Code Snippet:
Spinner Click :

```
    spinner_index_list?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

            //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, pos: Int, id: Long) {
                mRecyclerView?.visibility = View.GONE

                //Select item from spinner calling API
                val symbolDefaultGroup = SymbolForDefaultGroup(indexExchangeSegmentList[pos], parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString())
                grpIndexViewModel.getSearchSymbol(symbolDefaultGroup)?.observe(this@FragmentWatchlist, Observer { instrumentByIdResponse ->
                    mDataProvider = ExpandableDataProvider(instrumentByIdResponse)
                    mRecyclerView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    if (instrumentByIdResponse != null)
                        initRecyclerView(savedInstanceState)
                })
            }
```

ViewModel :

```
    fun getSearchSymbol(symbolForDefaultGroup: SymbolForDefaultGroup): LiveData<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>? {
    instrumentByIdResponse = null
    instrumentByIdResponse = MutableLiveData<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>()
    instrumentByIdResponse = groupRepository.getSearchSymbol(symbolForDefaultGroup)
    L.d("get symbol for default group method")
    return instrumentByIdResponse
}
```

Repository:

```
    override fun getSearchSymbol(symbolForDefaultGroup: SymbolForDefaultGroup): LiveData<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>> {
    val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>()
    val instrumentsIdList = ArrayList<Instrument>()
    val marketDataQuotesList = ArrayList<QuotesList>()
    val subscriptionList = ArrayList<SubscriptionList>()

    val symbolFroDefaultGroup: Observable<BaseResponse<SymbolForDefaultGroupResponse>> = remoteServices.requestSymbolForDefaultGroup(symbolForDefaultGroup)
    symbolFroDefaultGroup
            .flatMap { response ->
                for (i in 0 until response.result!!.instruments.size) {
                    instrumentsIdList.add(Instrument(EnumConfig.getExchangeSegment(response.result.exchangeSegment)!!.toInt(), response.result.instruments[i].toInt()))
                    marketDataQuotesList.add(QuotesList(EnumConfig.getExchangeSegment(response.result.exchangeSegment)!!.toInt(), response.result.instruments[i].toInt()))
                    subscriptionList.add(SubscriptionList(EnumConfig.getExchangeSegment(response.result.exchangeSegment)!!.toInt(), response.result.instruments[i].toInt()))
                }

                val instrumentByIdResult = InstrumentById(instrumentsIdList)
                val marketDataQuotes = MarketDataQuotes("ABC", "ABC", marketDataQuotesList, 1111)
                val subscriptionList = Subscribe("ABC", "ABC", "Mobile", subscriptionList, 1111)

                return@flatMap getDetails(instrumentByIdResult, marketDataQuotes, subscriptionList)

            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : ErrorCallBack<BaseResponse<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>>() {
                override fun onSuccess(t: BaseResponse<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>) {
                    L.d("Success of Search Instrument")
                    mutableLiveData.value = transform1(t)
                }
            })
    return mutableLiveData
}

private fun transform1(response: BaseResponse<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>?): List<InstrumentByIdResponse>? {
    return response!!.result!!.toList()
}

fun getDetails(instrumentById: InstrumentById, marketDataQuotes: MarketDataQuotes, subscription: Subscribe): Observable<DetailsModel> {

    return Observable.zip(
            remoteServices.requestInstrumentById(instrumentById),
            remoteServices.requestMarketDataQuotes(marketDataQuotes),
            remoteServices.requestSubscribe(subscription),
            /*Observable.fromArray(remoteServices.requestInstrumentById(instrumentById)),
            Observable.fromArray(remoteServices.requestMarketDataQuotes(marketDataQuotes)),
            Observable.fromArray(remoteServices.requestSubscribe(subscription)),*/

            Function3<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>, MarketDataQuotesResponse, SubscribeResult, DetailsModel>
            { instrumentByIdResponse, marketDataQuotesResponse, subscribeResponse ->
                createDetailsModel(instrumentByIdResponse, marketDataQuotesResponse, subscribeResponse)
            })
}

private fun createDetailsModel(instrumentByIdResponse: List<InstrumentByIdResponse>, marketDataQuotesResponse: MarketDataQuotesResponse, subscribeResult: SubscribeResult): DetailsModel {
     return DetailsModel(instrumentByIdResponse, marketDataQuotesResponse, subscribeResult)
}

 data class DetailsModel(
        val instrument: List<InstrumentByIdResponse>,
        val marketDataQuotes: MarketDataQuotesResponse,
        val subscribe: SubscribeResult)
```

RemoteService :

```
    fun requestInstrumentById(instrumentById: InstrumentById) = ApiService.requestInstrumentById(instrumentById)
```

APIService :

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("search/instrumentsbyid")
fun requestInstrumentById(@Body instrumentById: InstrumentById): Observable<BaseResponse<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>>>
```

[API Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6CWF.png)

[Error that i get on Zip Operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLVcw.png)

Comment: Have you tried applying `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` on each of the `remoteServices` call in that `zip`? `remoteServices.requestInstrumentById(instrumentById).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` etc.

Comment: Yes i have try that as well but still facing the issue

Comment: private fun getDetailsInstrumentById(instrumentById: InstrumentById): ObservableSource<List<InstrumentByIdResponse>> {
        return remoteServices.requestInstrumentById(instrumentById)
                .map {
                    it.result
                }
    }